# Spring Data JPA composite key as EmbeddedId not working, gives error upon getting the mapped entity

Tags: spring-data-jpa

Spring Data JPA, composite key as @EmbeddedId not working. Sharing code below as simply as possibly. Using lombok so the get/set/cons are not shown. Below is a problem example I was trying to achieve.

Users entity:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String email;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "primaryKey.user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<UserGroup> userGroups = new HashSet<UserGroup>();

}
```

Groups entity:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "groups")
public class Group {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "group_id")
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "primaryKey.group", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<UserGroup> userGroups = new HashSet<UserGroup>();

}
```

User and Group key:

```
@Data
@Embeddable
public class UserGroupId implements Serializable {

    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "user_id")
    @ManyToOne
    private User user;

    @JoinColumn(name = "group_id", referencedColumnName = "group_id")
    @ManyToOne
    private Group group;

}
```

User and Group mapping entity:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "users_groups")
@AssociationOverrides({
        @AssociationOverride(name = "primaryKey.user", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "user_id")),
        @AssociationOverride(name = "primaryKey.group", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "group_id", referencedColumnName = "group_id")) })
public class UserGroup {

    @EmbeddedId
    private UserGroupId primaryKey = new UserGroupId();

    @Column(name = "activated")
    private Boolean activated;

}
```

Gives error "com.sun.jdi.InvocationException: Exception occurred in target VM occurred invoking method" upon invoking [user.userGroups].

Comment: Can u share the code snippet where you are facing the issue

Comment: not able to fetch below:

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "primaryKey.user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<UserGroup> userGroups = new HashSet<UserGroup>();